# Definite article in attribute object sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Is that true that example (2) is incorrect? Or are the both correct but example (1) refers to a single incident, act of honesty?

1. I admire the honesty in him.
2. I admire honesty in him.

If we change the quantity of the possessor, is it better then to skip the article?

3. I admire honesty in people.

Comment: (1) is acceptable, but needs context to make it so. Standalone, 'I admire his honesty' is far more idiomatic. // I'm struggling to find any licensing context for (2). // (3) is fine; I can also see situations where adding 'the' would work. //// I'm not sure that this wasn't closed too quickly; there's a good question here, begging for explanations as to _why_ (2) is iffy at best while (3) works well (a trait common to a broad subset).